`Error: kexec load failed` (when trying to boot Ubuntu 24.04 from usb)
I've just come into possession of a IBM S822LC 8335 Power 8 2U Server. I'm having some difficulty installing the latest version of Ubuntu Server (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS).
I'm trying to choose how to the option "Try or Install Ubuntu Server" option, but at the bottom of the screen it says Error: kexec load failed
Is this due to some kernel mismatch? The USB's Ubuntu 24.04.1 has kernel 6.8 while this screen is showing kernels in the 4s. I plan on wiping all the data, so data loss is not an issue at all here.
That's my only guess. I'm a total newby, though. Any idea how to fix this? I've tried remaking the USB with startup disk creator a few times. I run Ubuntu Desktop on all my laptops and PCs, but this is my first time fiddling with a physical server.


Turns out I created a bootable usb correctly, but just with the wrong .iso image. Adding "little endian" to my search query found me the right iso.
I did stumble across this setup manual, but chose to disregard it because I couldn't really figure out the ipmitool
Also, it appears nothing past Ubuntu 20.04 will ever be available for this type of processor. Bootable usbs with higher versions just trigger reboots, and trying sudo do-release-upgrade from a working 20.04 tells me nothing past 20.04 will ever be available and that upgrades for this version will cease sometime in 2025.
